# Excel COUNTIF where number of cells to meet criteria range is non-contiguous

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am looking to use the =count function (or one of its family) to count how many times a value >2 appears in Column B where the range (number of rows) is dictated by how many rows in Column A are within a pre-set interval from the adjacent cell in Column A. But, the intervals between cells in Column 1 are highly variable. I have seen many answers addressing dynamic ranges but none appear to deal with this scenario.

I have created a mini-dataset (linked photo) as an example. I want to create an equation in Column C to count how many times "2" appears where the range is within a range that is plus or minus 0.2 from the adjacent cell in Column A. So, for C3, the range will be B1:B5 but for C4, B2:B5 and for C5, the range will be only B3:B5.

[image: Example dataset]

I appreciate I could do the count manually in this example but my actual dataset comprises many hundreds of cells. I have attempted all sorts of IF statements, including pre-calculating what X+0.2 and X-0.2 are in new columns, without success.

Many thanks in advance for any helpful tips.

Answer (score 2):

use COUNTIFS():

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,">=" & A1-0.2,A:A,"<=" & A1+0.2,B:B,2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to achieve it with `=SUMPRODUCT()`:

[image]

This is the formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ABS($A$1:$A$11-A5)<=0.2)*(--(B1:B11=2)))
```

The trick is that `ABS()` only returns a positive value, thus `-0,1` is evaluated to `0,1`.

Answer (score -1):

I'm trying to do something similar, but with multiple criteria. This works for me:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS([@[D1 Activity]], Activity_Participation),COUNTIFS([@[D2 Activity]], Activity_Participation),COUNTIFS([@[D3 Activity]], Activity_Participation),COUNTIFS([@[D4 Activity]], Activity_Participation),COUNTIFS([@[D5 Activity]], Activity_Participation),COUNTIFS([@[D6 Activity]], Activity_Participation),COUNTIFS([@[D7 Activity]],Activity_Participation),COUNTIFS([@[D8 Activity]], Activity_Participation),COUNTIFS([@[D9 Activity]], Activity_Participation),COUNTIFS([@D10Activity], Activity_Participation),COUNTIFS([@D11Activity], Activity_Participation),COUNTIFS([@[12  Activity]],Activity_Participation))
```

Where Activity_Participation is a range of values (or formulas even?) to check